# ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

Facing this issue and already post of similar doesn't have solution, So re-posting this again with more logs and info.

Below is my wdio.conf.js file.

```
const path = require('path')

exports.config = {
    //
    // ====================
    // Runner Configuration
    // ====================
    //
    port: 4723,
    path: '/wd/hub',
    //
    // ==================
    // Specify Test Files
    // ==================
    // Define which test specs should run. The pattern is relative to the directory
    // from which `wdio` was called.
    //
    // The specs are defined as an array of spec files (optionally using wildcards
    // that will be expanded). The test for each spec file will be run in a separate
    // worker process. In order to have a group of spec files run in the same worker
    // process simply enclose them in an array within the specs array.
    //
    // If you are calling `wdio` from an NPM script (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script),
    // then the current working directory is where your `package.json` resides, so `wdio`
    // will be called from there.
    //
    specs: [
        './test/specs/**/*.js'
    ],
    // Patterns to exclude.
    exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
    ],
    //
    // ============
    // Capabilities
    // ============
    // Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilities at the same
    // time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test
    // sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude options in
    // order to group specific specs to a specific capability.
    //
    // First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's
    // say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have
    // set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec
    // files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time
    // and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities
    // from the same test should run tests.
    //
    maxInstances: 1,
    //
    // If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the
    // Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities:
    // https://saucelabs.com/platform/platform-configurator
    //
    capabilities: [{
        "platformName": "Android",
        "appium:udid": "emulator-5554",
        "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
        "appium:app": "C:\\Users\\Ramkumar\\learnings\\study\\mock-appium-webdriverio\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk"
      }],
    //
    // ===================
    // Test Configurations
    // ===================
    // Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
    //
    // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
    logLevel: 'info',
    //
    // Set specific log levels per logger
    // loggers:
    // - webdriver, webdriverio
    // - @wdio/browserstack-service, @wdio/devtools-service, @wdio/sauce-service
    // - @wdio/mocha-framework, @wdio/jasmine-framework
    // - @wdio/local-runner
    // - @wdio/sumologic-reporter
    // - @wdio/cli, @wdio/config, @wdio/utils
    // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
    // logLevels: {
    //     webdriver: 'info',
    //     '@wdio/appium-service': 'info'
    // },
    //
    // If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed use
    // bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests).
    bail: 0,
    //
    // Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter starts
    // with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your baseUrl.
    // If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the base url
    // gets prepended directly.
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
    //
    // Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    //
    // Default timeout in milliseconds for request
    // if browser driver or grid doesn't send response
    connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
    //
    // Default request retries count
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    //
    // Test runner services
    // Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
    // your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
    // commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.
    // services: [
    //     'appium'
    // ],

    services: [
        ['appium', {
            args: {
                address: 'localhost',
                port: 4723
            },
            logPath:'./',
        }]
    ],
    
    // Framework you want to run your specs with.
    // The following are supported: Mocha, Jasmine, and Cucumber
    // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/frameworks
    //
    // Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed
    // before running any tests.
    framework: 'mocha',
    //
    // The number of times to retry the entire specfile when it fails as a whole
    // specFileRetries: 1,
    //
    // Delay in seconds between the spec file retry attempts
    // specFileRetriesDelay: 0,
    //
    // Whether or not retried specfiles should be retried immediately or deferred to the end of the queue
    // specFileRetriesDeferred: false,
    //
    // Test reporter for stdout.
    // The only one supported by default is 'dot'
    // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/dot-reporter
    reporters: ['spec'],


    
    //
    // Options to be passed to Mocha.
    // See the full list at http://mochajs.org/
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000
    },
    //
    // =====
    // Hooks
    // =====
    // WebdriverIO provides several hooks you can use to interfere with the test process in order to enhance
    // it and to build services around it. You can either apply a single function or an array of
    // methods to it. If one of them returns with a promise, WebdriverIO will wait until that promise got
    // resolved to continue.
    /**
     * Gets executed once before all workers get launched.
     * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     */
    // onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed before a worker process is spawned and can be used to initialise specific service
     * for that worker as well as modify runtime environments in an async fashion.
     * @param  {String} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)
     * @param  {[type]} caps     object containing capabilities for session that will be spawn in the worker
     * @param  {[type]} specs    specs to be run in the worker process
     * @param  {[type]} args     object that will be merged with the main configuration once worker is initialized
     * @param  {[type]} execArgv list of string arguments passed to the worker process
     */
    // onWorkerStart: function (cid, caps, specs, args, execArgv) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed just after a worker process has exited.
     * @param  {String} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)
     * @param  {Number} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
     * @param  {[type]} specs    specs to be run in the worker process
     * @param  {Number} retries  number of retries used
     */
    // onWorkerEnd: function (cid, exitCode, specs, retries) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed just before initialising the webdriver session and test framework. It allows you
     * to manipulate configurations depending on the capability or spec.
     * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
     * @param {String} cid worker id (e.g. 0-0)
     */
    // beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs, cid) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
     * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs        List of spec file paths that are to be run
     * @param {Object}         browser      instance of created browser/device session
     */
    // before: function (capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
     * Runs before a WebdriverIO command gets executed.
     * @param {String} commandName hook command name
     * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
     */
    // beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) {
    // },
    /**
     * Hook that gets executed before the suite starts
     * @param {Object} suite suite details
     */
    // beforeSuite: function (suite) {
    // },
    /**
     * Function to be executed before a test (in Mocha/Jasmine) starts.
     */
    // beforeTest: function (test, context) {
    // },
    /**
     * Hook that gets executed _before_ a hook within the suite starts (e.g. runs before calling
     * beforeEach in Mocha)
     */
    // beforeHook: function (test, context) {
    // },
    /**
     * Hook that gets executed _after_ a hook within the suite starts (e.g. runs after calling
     * afterEach in Mocha)
     */
    // afterHook: function (test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
    // },
    /**
     * Function to be executed after a test (in Mocha/Jasmine only)
     * @param {Object}  test             test object
     * @param {Object}  context          scope object the test was executed with
     * @param {Error}   result.error     error object in case the test fails, otherwise `undefined`
     * @param {Any}     result.result    return object of test function
     * @param {Number}  result.duration  duration of test
     * @param {Boolean} result.passed    true if test has passed, otherwise false
     * @param {Object}  result.retries   informations to spec related retries, e.g. `{ attempts: 0, limit: 0 }`
     */
    // afterTest: function(test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
    // },


    /**
     * Hook that gets executed after the suite has ended
     * @param {Object} suite suite details
     */
    // afterSuite: function (suite) {
    // },
    /**
     * Runs after a WebdriverIO command gets executed
     * @param {String} commandName hook command name
     * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
     * @param {Number} result 0 - command success, 1 - command error
     * @param {Object} error error object if any
     */
    // afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed after all tests are done. You still have access to all global variables from
     * the test.
     * @param {Number} result 0 - test pass, 1 - test fail
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
     */
    // after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed right after terminating the webdriver session.
     * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
     */
    // afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit. An error
     * thrown in the onComplete hook will result in the test run failing.
     * @param {Object} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
     * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {<Object>} results object containing test results
     */
    // onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {
    // },
    /**
    * Gets executed when a refresh happens.
    * @param {String} oldSessionId session ID of the old session
    * @param {String} newSessionId session ID of the new session
    */
    // onReload: function(oldSessionId, newSessionId) {
    // }
}
```

I have the config which I want to highlight in this above file.

```
{
port: 4723,
path: '/wd/hub',
capabilities: [{
    "platformName": "Android",
    "appium:udid": "emulator-5554",
    "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
    "appium:app": "C:\\Users\\Ramkumar\\learnings\\study\\mock-appium-webdriverio\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk"
  }],

services: [
    ['appium', {
        args: {
            address: 'localhost',
            port: 4723
        },
        logPath:'./',
    }]
],
}
```

Now running the command npx wdio .\wdio.conf.js gives me the error.

```
PS C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio> npx wdio .\wdio.conf.js
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

Execution of 1 workers started at 2022-06-07T10:58:18.805Z

2022-06-07T10:58:18.820Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2022-06-07T10:58:27.952Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
Error: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: 1)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\@wdio\appium-service\build\launcher.js:110:22)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)

Continue...
2022-06-07T10:58:27.956Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2022-06-07T10:58:27.957Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: .\\wdio.conf.js
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.404Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] RUNNING in Android - C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\test\specs\example.e2e.js
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.583Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.646Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.646Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   capabilities: {
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
[0-0]       platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]       'appium:udid': 'emulator-5554',
[0-0]       'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
[0-0]       'appium:app': 'C:\\Users\\Ramkumar\\learnings\\study\\mock-appium-webdriverio\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk'   
[0-0]     },
[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: {
[0-0]     platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]     'appium:udid': 'emulator-5554',
[0-0]     'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
[0-0]     'appium:app': 'C:\\Users\\Ramkumar\\learnings\\study\\mock-appium-webdriverio\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk'     
[0-0]   }
[0-0] }
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.686Z WARN webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.686Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 1/3
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.686Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.686Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   capabilities: {
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
[0-0]       platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]       'appium:udid': 'emulator-5554',
[0-0]       'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
[0-0]       'appium:app': 'C:\\Users\\Ramkumar\\learnings\\study\\mock-appium-webdriverio\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk'   
[0-0]     },
[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: {
[0-0]     platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]     'appium:udid': 'emulator-5554',
[0-0]     'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
[0-0]     'appium:app': 'C:\\Users\\Ramkumar\\learnings\\study\\mock-appium-webdriverio\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk'     
[0-0]   }
[0-0] }
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.693Z WARN webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.693Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 2/3
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.693Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.693Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   capabilities: {
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
[0-0]       platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]       'appium:udid': 'emulator-5554',
[0-0]       'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
[0-0]       'appium:app': 'C:\\Users\\Ramkumar\\learnings\\study\\mock-appium-webdriverio\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk'   
[0-0]     },
[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: {
[0-0]     platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]     'appium:udid': 'emulator-5554',
[0-0]     'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
[0-0]     'appium:app': 'C:\\Users\\Ramkumar\\learnings\\study\\mock-appium-webdriverio\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk'     
[0-0]   }
[0-0] }
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.700Z WARN webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.701Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 3/3
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.701Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.701Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   capabilities: {
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
[0-0]       platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]       'appium:udid': 'emulator-5554',
[0-0]       'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
[0-0]       'appium:app': 'C:\\Users\\Ramkumar\\learnings\\study\\mock-appium-webdriverio\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk'
[0-0]     },
[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: {
[0-0]     platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]     'appium:udid': 'emulator-5554',
[0-0]     'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
[0-0]     'appium:app': 'C:\\Users\\Ramkumar\\learnings\\study\\mock-appium-webdriverio\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk'     
[0-0]   }
[0-0] }
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.707Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to unknown command: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.707Z ERROR webdriver: unknown command: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
[0-0]     at getErrorFromResponseBody (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\webdriver\build\utils.js:197:12)
[0-0]     at NodeJSRequest._request (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\webdriver\build\request\index.js:166:60)
[0-0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[0-0]     at async startWebDriverSession (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\webdriver\build\utils.js:67:20)
[0-0]     at async Function.newSession (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\webdriver\build\index.js:46:45)
[0-0]     at async remote (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\webdriverio\build\index.js:77:22)
[0-0]     at async Runner._startSession (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\@wdio\runner\build\index.js:223:56)
[0-0]     at async Runner._initSession (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\@wdio\runner\build\index.js:176:25)
[0-0]     at async Runner.run (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\@wdio\runner\build\index.js:88:19)
[0-0] 2022-06-07T10:58:28.708Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
[0-0] The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
[0-0]     at startWebDriverSession (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\webdriver\build\utils.js:72:15)
[0-0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[0-0]     at async Function.newSession (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\webdriver\build\index.js:46:45)
[0-0]     at async remote (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\webdriverio\build\index.js:77:22)
[0-0]     at async Runner._startSession (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\@wdio\runner\build\index.js:223:56)
[0-0]     at async Runner._initSession (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\@wdio\runner\build\index.js:176:25)
[0-0]     at async Runner.run (C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\node_modules\@wdio\runner\build\index.js:88:19)
[0-0] FAILED in Android - C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio\test\specs\example.e2e.js
2022-06-07T10:58:28.827Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook
2022-06-07T10:58:28.828Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:10

2022-06-07T10:58:28.830Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2022-06-07T10:58:29.095Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2022-06-07T10:58:29.097Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
PS C:\Users\Ramkumar\learnings\study\mock-appium-webdriverio>
```

I try to invoke the same with Appium tool, its invoking the application.

[image]

Appium opening the application for inspection.

[image]

Emulator opening the apps screen shot

[image]

Appium Server Screen shot

[image]

**Let me know if any other setting is required.**

Thanks,
Ramkumar

Comment: Maybe you can post your test file, it might help identifying the problem.

Comment: @WhiT3Kr0w , i do not have anything in specs as of now. 'describe('My Login application', () => {
    it('should login with valid credentials',  () => {
        // await LoginPage.open();

        // await LoginPage.login('tomsmith', 'SuperSecretPassword!');
        // await expect(SecurePage.flashAlert).toBeExisting();
        // await expect(SecurePage.flashAlert).toHaveTextContaining(
        //     'You logged into a secure area!');
    });
});'

Answer (score 1):

I had that message coming up on my terminal as well.
Turns out I had appium service running on my terminal while I ran my WebdriverIO tests.

terminating the appium service running on my terminal and only running my WebdriverIO test got rid of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Some site video session mentioned about having "appium:platformVersion" as one more properties in capabilities and adding one more version of emulator will solve this problem.

Earlier I have having only one emulator [Android version 'R']. Now I added one more emulator with [Android version 'Q']. After adding the "appium:platformVersion" in capabilities, its working fine.

> capabilities defined in wdio.conf.js [previous]

```
capabilities: [{
    "platformName": "Android",
    "appium:udid": "d278263c",
    "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
    "appium:app": "C:\\Users\\Ramkumar\\learnings\\study\\mock-appium-webdriverio\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk"
  }],
```

> capabilities defined in wdio.conf.js [New one]

```
capabilities: [{
        "platformName": "Android",
        "appium:udid": "d278263c",
        "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
        "appium:app": "C:\\Users\\Ramkumar\\learnings\\study\\mock-appium-webdriverio\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk",
        "appium:platformVersion": "9"
      }],
```

Kindly note this observations:

1. Every time executing the script with **"appium:platformVersion": "9"** always works and its starting the application.
2. After adding one more device [earlier I had only one device], if I execute the script without "appium:platformVersion": "9", some time it works and some time it throws me same error *"ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook"*
3. Even when I have only one emulator [deleted the new one created], executing with capabilities "appium:platformVersion": "9" always works and its starting the application.

*This works on both emualator and android real device. Above mentioned capabilities is for my personal device Oneplus 5 [Android Version 9]*

I'm not sure if this is change mentioned above works and it started working, but I have not changed anything else in the project or my laptop. If someone facing this issue can try this solution... If it resolve or still facing the issue, kindly leave a comment for others....

Answer (score 0):

your config says that your path is `/wd/hub` , but your appium server is pointing to `/`. Appium server path is not configurable with GUI, so you can

- set your path in your config to

```
  {
    port: 4723,
    path: '/',
    ...
  }
```

- or manually launch appium server in a terminal and use [these settings](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/server-args/index.html) :

```
appium --base-path /wd/hub --port 4723
```

Also, set your capabilities following [this link](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/).